# PyCharm - how to rename all identifiers in project to snake_case automatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have a pretty large project in Python (little over 3000 lines) and unfortunately, the syntax doesn't respect PEP8, which is needed now. I'm looking especially for the way of renaming all the functions from `camelCase` style to `snake_case` style.

So far I've only found [this answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206174959-Code-formatting-replacing-with-camelCase-everywhere), which rejects the possibility of renaming all variable automatically in PyCharm and suggests doing it manually, which I don't want to because there are thousands of variables in the code.

So, is there a way, how to rename all the variables automatically according to the rule above?

I'm not interested in functions/regexes, which do it for one string, I'm really only interested in the "collective" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [camel-snake-pep8](https://github.com/abarker/camel-snake-pep8), as from official description:

> A refactoring tool to help convert camel case to snake case and vice
>   versa in a Python program, in conformity with the PEP-8 style guide.
>   It uses/abuses Python-Rope to find and perform the changes. The
>   program interactively displays proposed changes and queries the user
>   as to whether or not to accept the changes.

To install run these commands:

```
$ <activate your virtual environment>
$ pip install rope colorama
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abarker/camel-snake-pep8/master/src/camel_snake_pep8/camel_snake_pep8.py
```

After that go to the project's folder and run this command:

```
$ python2 camel_snake_pep8.py . *.py
```

The program can be used to refactor either Python 2 or Python 3 code **but it must be run with Python 2**. This is because, as of Mar. 2017, Python-Rope only supports Python 2 (a Python 3 version is said to be in progress).
Sometimes this won't work, because of specific syntax for python 3, e.g.:

```
def pick(l: list, index: int) -> int:
    return l[index]
```

In this case you have to make syntax of such expressions compatible with python2. Please, vote/help rope project's [issue](https://github.com/python-rope/rope/issues/57) to support python3.

Comment: now can be used with Python3 too:

 The program can be used to refactor either Python 2 or Python 3 code. **Run the program with the same version of Python as the code that is being modified.**
source : https://github.com/abarker/camel-snake-pep8